# I cant get my m4A1 viewmodel in roblox studio to show up, how do i fix it?

Tags: lua, viewmodel, roblox

**hi recently i made a viewmodel for the m4a1 in my roblox game however when i finished the code it didnt work. i went through it multiple times if anyone can spot the error i would greatly appreciate it:)**

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer 
local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait() 

local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")  
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService") 

local camera = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera 

local framework = {
    inventory = {
        "M4A1";
        "M9"; 
        "KNIFE";
        "FRAG";
    };
    
    module = nil; 
    viewmodel = nil;
} 

function loadSlot(Item)
    local viewmodelFolder = game.ReplicatedStorage.Viewmodels 
    local moduleFolder = game.ReplicatedStorage.Modules 
    
    if moduleFolder:FindFirstChild("Item") then 
        framework.module = require(moduleFolder:FindFirstChild(Item))
        
        if viewmodelFolder:FindFirstChild("Item") then 
            framework.viewmodel = viewmodelFolder:FindFirstChild(Item):Clone()
            framework.viewmodel.Parent = camera
        end
    end
end 

RunService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()
    for i, v in pairs(camera:GetChildren()) do 
        if v:IsA("Model")then 
            v:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(camera.CFrame)
        end
    end
end)

loadSlot(framework.inventory[1])
```

Comment: Did you run it? Did it output any kind of error?

Comment: no error just didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Try this one I remade it little it should work

```
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local character = player.Character or player.CharacterAdded:Wait()

local UserInputService = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")

local camera = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera

local framework = {

    inventory = {

        "M4A1",

        "A",

        "B",

        "C",

    },

    module = nil,

    viewmodel = nil,

}

function loadSlot(Item)

    local viewmodelFolder = game.ReplicatedStorage.Viewmodels

    local moduleFolder = game.ReplicatedStorage.Modules

    if moduleFolder:FindFirstChild(Item) then

        framework.module = require(moduleFolder:FindFirstChild(Item))

        if viewmodelFolder:FindFirstChild(Item) then

            framework.viewmodel = viewmodelFolder:FindFirstChild(Item):Clone()

            framework.viewmodel.Parent = camera

        end

    end

end

RunService.RenderStepped:Connect(function()

    for i, v in pairs(camera:GetChildren()) do

        if v:IsA("Model") then

            v:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(camera.CFrame)

        end

    end

end)

loadSlot(framework.inventory[1])
```